# How to Bind the Values of an Array of Doubles to a Large Number of Labels in JavaFX 2

Tags: binding, javafx

I am trying to create a simulation program that will count the number of times two players will get certain combination of cards out of a large number of trials. Currently, I have neatly positioned a bunch of labels using JavaFX's Scene Builder in a table and have their fx:id's referenced in my controller class. Each time I run the simulation one of 20+ outcomes will occur. And each time a certain outcome happens I want to add one to the the appropriate label. Also I want to see the values on the labels update as the computer does its calculations.

Currently I have a simple integer array that keeps track of the number of times an outcome happened. However, I am having trouble binding that integer array to the labels. The potential solution that I found

```
int i = 0;
Label.textProperty().bind(String.valueOf(i));
```

does not seem to work. Furthermore, I have tried doing numerous things with DoubleProperties and NumberBindings, but, to be honest, I don't have a clue what I am doing. Can someone please explain to me a simple solution for this problem or provide me a reference for bindings in JavaFX 2 that are relevant to my problem (I have read oracle's one page tutorial on bindings but it did not seem exactly relevant)?

Comment: The binding needs to be done to a Property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the basic binding stuff [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).
For what I think you are trying to do, you have to remember you can only bind Property objects, not primitives, not Strings, nor any other object.

Having said that, you have to wrap any data in a appropiate Property Object, for example if you want to show a String on a Label:

```
        StringProperty value = new SimpleStringProperty("Hello");
        label.textProperty().bind(value);
```

You can then change the value on the property, and the label will update:

```
        value.set("Bye");
```

This works OK for Strings because the text on the label is a String, but if your data is an Integer or a Double, you can use a converter:

```
        IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
        label.textProperty().bindBidirectional(value, new NumberStringConverter());
```

The same applies with doubles:

```
        DoubleProperty val = new SimpleDoubleProperty(12.5);
        tipText.textProperty().bindBidirectional(val, new NumberStringConverter());
```

You can also extend an existing Converter if you find youself in a situation where neither of them satisfy your needs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that if you don't need bidirectional binding, which is probably not that useful for a label, you could simply do `label.textProperty().bind(value.asString());`.